# Asynchronously processing tasks with concurrent processing

Tags: java, apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

we had a requirement to process multiple tasks concurrently and each of these tasks takes nearly 10 sec to complete processing. Our camel routes looks like this.

```
<route id="routeA">
<from uri="activemq:queue:queueA" />
<to uri="direct-vm:genericProcessing" />
</route>

<routeid="routeB">
<from uri="activemq:queue:queueB" />
<to uri="direct-vm:genericProcessing" />
</route>

<route id="routeC">
<from uri="direct-vm:genericProcessing" />
<!--Run business rules -->
<inOnly uri="vm:timeTakingRoute" /> <!-- this takes 10 sec  to complete />
</route>
```

From vm:timeTakingRoute request should run in single thread as it requires DB transactions.If we use inOnly exchange pattern with vm endpoint, request runs asynchronously but as request takes minimum of 10 sec to process completely from here, other request might pile up untill 1st request completes. How can we spawn threads to run requests concurrently. Possibles options I can think off is having concurrentconsumers option on vm, replacing vm with activemq with concurrent consumers defined, replace vm with wiretap with custom threadpool or define  like below?

```
<threads>
   <to uri="vm:timeTakingRoute" />
</threads>
```

What would be the best possible option to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

generally I just increase the consumer threads reading from queues using the maxConcurrentConsumers property...this multi-threads the downstream processing

```
<route id="routeA">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:queueA?maxConcurrentConsumers=10" />
    <to uri="direct-vm:genericProcessing" />
</route>
```

other options

- use the [async](http://camel.apache.org/async.html) API for inonly operations to not block the client call
- use the concurrentConsumers on the vm component (as you suggested)
- add another queue hop to decouple/multi-thread (seda, activemq) a downstream in-only process

Comment: We already defined maxConcurrentConsumers for queues. What i am asking is for vm:timeTakingRoute. How to scale this up???